# ¿como cambiar la segunda letra de cada string en un array en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, string

Por ejemplo:

```
let familia=['mario','julia','benicio','sasha'];
```

Debo cambiar la segunda letra de cada string por una X.

He probado distintos métodos y no me sale

Comment: Deberias agregar lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes iterar por el arreglo y sustituir el elemento por la concatenación del primer caracter, una `X` y el resto de la cadena.

Para obtener el primer elemento, utiliza el método `substr`, y para hallar el resto de la cadena, puedes valerte del método `substring`.

Algo como:

```js
let familia = ['mario', 'julia', 'benicio', 'sasha'];
let idx;
for (idx in familia) {
    //sustituyo cada elemento del arreglo por la concatenación.
    familia[idx] = familia[idx].substr(0, 1) + 'X' + familia[idx].substring(2);
}
//veamos el resultado en consola
for (idx in familia) {
    console.log(familia[idx]);
}
```

Comment: Ante todo muchas gracias. En el caso de los que somos principiantes, se puede cambiar con con un for anidado?

Comment: Si, podría hacerse de muchas formas distintas.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```js
let familia=['mario','julia','benicio','sasha'];
const resultado = familia.map(f => (f.substr(0, 1) + "X" + f.substr(1 + 1)) );
console.log(resultado)
```

Se utiliza un map para iterar el arreglo y el substr para obtener una cadena de caracteres a partir de un indice y se le concatena la "X"

Links de referencia:

[Función map de los arreglos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)

[Función substr de los strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substr)

Answer (score 0):

Una opción usando el callback de `replace()`:

```js
let familia = ['mario', 'julia', 'benicio', 'sasha'];

familia = familia.map(e => e.replace(/\w/g, (l, i) => i === 1 ? 'X' : l));

console.log(familia);
```